# Deﬁne a control sequence \ic such that ‘\ic c’ puts the italic correction of character c into TeX’s register \dimen0

Tags: italic, lengths, italic-correction

On page 14 of the book **The TeXbook**, the exercise 4.3 is

> Deﬁne a control sequence `\ic` such that ‘`\ic c`’ puts the italic correction of character `c` into TeX's register `\dimen0`.

The answer is `\def\ic#1{\setbox0=\hbox{#1\/}\dimen0=\wd0\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\advance\dimen0 by -\wd0}`

I knew the `\def\ic#1{<stuff>}` define a command `\ic` containing contents. But how to understand the contents in the `{<stuff>}` of `\def\ic#1{\setbox0=\hbox{#1\/}\dimen0=\wd0\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\advance\dimen0 by -\wd0}`?  And I even don't know what is the exercise talk about. In this exercise, what is the function of `\dimen0`? Why should we do this?

In other programming languages, sentences are often broken during relatively long statements. There are delimiters when breaking sentences, such as semicolon in Perl and tab in Python. It seems that there is no delimiter in TeX?

---

Does this work too?`\def\ic#1{\setbox0=\hbox{#1\/}\dimen0=\wd0\setbox1=\hbox{#1}\advance\dimen0 by -\wd1}`

Comment: Which bit do you want help understanding? The first `\def` defines `\ic` such that it puts the argument `#1` into a horizontal box, together with its italic correction, and sets a box equal to that hbox. It then sets a dimension register (`\dimen0`) equal to the width of that that box. Then it resets the box so it is equal to an hbox which contains the character without the following italic correction. Then it subtracts the width of the reset box from the dimension register So what remains in the dimension register is the italic correction alone.

Comment: @cfr So, there are several steps, why there are no delimiters between steps? How did you seperate the steps?

Comment: If the commands are well-defined, their inputs can be anticipated, so there's no need to formally insert a delimiter between commands. For example, the "format" or specification of a `\def`inition is `\def<cs><args>{<stuff>}`. Anything else isn't acceptable, so given that, TeX knows what to expect, and will interpret whatever follows it independent from it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a delimiter. I know what 'delimiter' means in a bunch of senses, but not, I think, this one. `{` and `}` are delimiters in the sense that they're delimiting some arguments. But I don't think that's what you mean. Does bash have delimiters? I ask because I might understand that comparison.

Comment: @cfr If in Perl, `{\setbox0=\hbox{#1\/}\dimen0=\wd0\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\advance\dimen0 by -\wd0}` will be `{\setbox0=\hbox{#1\/}; \dimen0=\wd0; \setbox0=\hbox{#1}; \advance\dimen0 by -\wd0}`

Comment: @Werner I guess ambiguity arises in some cases. I haven't noticed it yet, but I'll keep an eye out for it.

Comment: @Y.zeng I don't speak `perl`. That's why I asked if `bash` had delimiters.

Comment: @cfr I don't know how to use  `bash`, but I will learn it in the future.

Comment: @Y.zeng Well, I can only guess what they do. If they are like semicolons in `sh` or `bash`, no TeX doesn't have delimiters like that. You'd be putting literal semicolons and spaces into the definition of `\ic`. I mean semicolons are used reasonably often in documents. So are spaces.

Comment: @cfr  I tested it. Space will work but semicolons not work.

Comment: @Y.zeng If you put spaces only where TeX will gobble them, they will make no difference to the output, but that is only because TeX gobbles them. If you put spaces in other places, they will be typeset.. Hunting stray spaces is a long-standing pastime of TeX users.

Comment: @cfr So, what do you mean of `You'd be putting literal semicolons and spaces into the definition of \ic`? If I put semicolons into the code, it will output wrong result.

Comment: Most TeX programmers would separate different parts of a macro into lines, but to avoid stray spaces we'd end the lines with `%` (make the end-of-lines into comments) - that doesn't meant that `%` is a delimiter

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks. % is a very useful symbol in LaTeX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*This answers an earlier version of the question, which explicitly stated the OP's desire to understand the method Knuth uses in the *TeXbook*. It does not explain how the italic correction of a character can best be ascertained with current TeX installations.*

### *Caveat emptor ...*

```
\def\ic#1{\setbox0=\hbox{#1\/}\dimen0=\wd0\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\advance\dimen0 by -\wd0}
```

Knuth's basic strategy: find the width of the character plus its italic correction then deduct the width of the character without its italic correction to get the width of its italic correction alone.

```
#1\/
```

The character followed by its italic correction is

```
\hbox{#1\/}
```

put into a horizontal box (i.e. as if typesetting in horizontal mode, but without typesetting anything) and

```
\setbox0=\hbox{#1\/}
```

box 0 (which is just a box) is set equal to the horizontal box.

```
\dimen0=\wd0
```

Set the dimension register `\dimen0` equal to the width of box 0. So this contains the width of the character plus its italic correction.

```
\hbox{#1}
```

Put the character and nothing but the character into a horizontal box

```
\setbox0=\hbox{#1}
```

and set box 0 equal to this horizontal box.

```
\wd0
```

The width of box 0, which is now the width of the character without its italic correction.

```
\advance\dimen0 by -\wd0
```

Subtract this value from the value stored in the dimension register `\dimen0`. So `\dimen0` now contains

```
width of character + width of italic correction - width of character
```

Hence

```
\def\ic#1{\setbox0=\hbox{#1\/}\dimen0=\wd0\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\advance\dimen0 by -\wd0}
```

means that `\ic#1` will store the width of `#1`'s italic correction into the dimension register `\dimen0`.

Or, to be more accurate, the value in `\dimen0` will approximate the italic correction of `#1` in the current context. The actual value will depend on font, size etc., but it will also be only approximate because TeX's calculations are only approximations. Generally, they are accurate enough for typesetting, but sometimes the discrepancies become problematic.

Comment: How can I see the width of italic correction in TeX? I want to see the exact width number and unit in TeX.

Comment: @Y.zeng Do you mean for `c`, say?

Comment: No, for italic correction of c that is result of `width of character + width of italic correction - width of character`. In TeX now, `\ic{hello} to` will get a little black and `to` in the ouput, but what is the width of the blank before the `to`?

Comment: @Y.zeng If so, start `tex`. Paste the definition of `\ic` in. Then say `\ic c` for `c` followed by `\showthe\dimen0`. But `c` is pretty boring. Try `V`.

Comment: Can't output it to the pdf file? By `\showthe\dimen0`, I can only see it in the log file.

Comment: @Y.zeng You can if you like. `\the\dimen0`.

Comment: Weird. I can get the result from `\ic{hello}\the\dimen0 to`, which is `.5556ptto`

Comment: It is not the same. The result of `\ic h\the\dimen0 to` is `.55557ptto`.

Comment: That said, TeX also has flaws, at least accuracy may be a problem in some case.

Comment: @Y.zeng Describing it as a 'flaw' is not entirely fair. It was designed this way for good reason. That the reasons no longer necessarily apply doesn't make the original design flawed.

Comment: How do you know  it is no longer necessary? I think every thing is necessary based on all the conditions.

Comment: Why I can use `\ic{hello}\the\dimen0 to` but can't use `\ic hello \the\dimen0 to`?

Comment: @Y.zeng - Regarding your question, "Why can I use `\ic{hello}\the\dimen0 to` but can't use `\ic hello \the\dimen0 to`?" In the first case, "hello" is the argument of `\ic`; in the second, it's "h".

Comment: `\ic{hello}` is measuring the italic correction of `o` @Y.zeng

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But the question asked wasn't how to get the italic correction. It was what Knuth's answer to that question was doing. How could an answer to *that* question not be a pre-etex answer?

Comment: @cfr hmm I guess you are right, I actually took it more as just answering the question in the title, but I'll delete the comment above/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I wondered how you could interpret it that way until I realised the question had changed. The version I answered said explicitly the OP was trying to understand everything in the TeX Book, so I answered in light of that. I ... er ... obviously(?) wouldn't actually go about determining a character's italic correction this way.

Comment: @Y.zeng Some of the design decisions in TeX are the result of limitations on computing resources which no longer apply. Compilation took comparatively large amounts of memory and processing resources, so inaccuracies which would affect the typeset result were avoided. If TeX were to be designed now, you wouldn't have to make the same choices because you wouldn't be trying to run it on 1970s hardware.

Comment: @cfr Now I understand why tex occasionally prompts that there is insufficient memory. It is a design limitation caused by the conditions at that time.

Answer (score 8):

When the TeXBook was written, to get the metrics such as height, width or italic correction of a character, you needed to set them in a box and measure box sizes, but e-Tex has been available for some decades now, and provides direct access to these lengths with primitive length commands that do not require box assignments so you can use them directly as lengths in `\typeout` or `\setlength` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\itshape

\typeout{\the\fontcharic\font`c}

\setlength{\dimen0}{\fontcharic\font`c}

\typeout{\the\dimen0}


\typeout{\the\fontcharic\font`f}

\setlength{\dimen0}{\fontcharic\font`f}

\typeout{\the\dimen0}

\end{document}
```

shows the italic correction of `c` and `f` in the current (italic) font in a `\typeout` and after assigning to `\dimen0`

It produces a log:

```
0.56528pt
0.56528pt
2.11945pt
2.11945pt
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's start from the end. Why `\dimen0`? Because it's a register where you can store a length. In a real world application, it would be a properly allocated and named register, but for the purpose of an exercise, `\dimen0` is as good as any other.

Why aren't statements terminated? Because there aren't statements like in other interpreted languages such as Perl or Python. The TeX language is primarily aimed to *typesetting text*. Using, say, a semicolon for “terminating statements” would lead to ambiguities as how to interpret such symbol: is it a text semicolon or a statement terminator?

In the sister language for Metafont, which is not aimed at typesetting, but at building fonts, semicolons are used for terminating statements. You have to accept that the language of TeX is *weird*.

Now, let's look at the proposed solution, namely

```
\def\ic#1{\setbox0=\hbox{#1\/}\dimen0=\wd0
\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\advance\dimen0 by -\wd0 }
```

Knuth's style is very compact and he tries hard to squeeze code in as few lines as possible. But you can split the “statements” yourself in more readable chunks:

```
\def\ic#1{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1\/}%
  \dimen0=\wd0
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  \advance\dimen0 by -\wd0
}
```

Note the presence or absence of `%` at the end of lines, you should train to place when necessary and to omit them when they aren't: remember that an endline counts as a space, unless it's masked with `%`.

The idea is to measure the width of a box containing the argument together with the italic correction (for the last character) and to store it in `\dimen0`. Then the same text is measured without the italic correction in place and the width is subtracted from the current value of `\dimen0`.

***Don't*** consider `%` as a statement terminator! It isn't. Why didn't I use it at the end of the `\dimen0=\wd0` line? Because `\wd` wants to see an integer after it and TeX will look for a space after a sequence of digits in order to know when it ends and will perform macro expansion in the process; the trailing space will be ignored by rule. Quoting from page 208

> For best results, *always put a blank space after a numeric constant*; this blank space tells TeX that the constant is complete, and such a space will never “get through” to the output.